# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, split

I get the error on the third line of the following (I need to retrieve all content from preformatted container and split it into lines):

```
$(function(){
    var tab = $('pre').html();
    var lines = tab.split('\n');
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: the error means tab is undefined so I would say the element `pre` doesn't exist

Comment: `html()` will return undefined, if the jQuery object does not contain any selected elements, eg `$('pre')` didnt find any `<pre>` elements

Comment: yep that's right, I was checking wrong page which didn't contain the <pre>. Thank you